# Best way to load models in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm not sure of the best way to load models in CakePHP 2.0 now.

---

**Question 1**

I have a model where more than one database field is related to another model.

`customers` table has the fields `country_origin`, `country_residence` and `country_study` and all of those fields contain an ID from the table `countries`.

So in my Customer model, how am I supposed to load the Country model?

---

**Question 2**

Has `Controller::loadModel()` been deprecated or is it bad practice to use this?  How am I supposed to load a model in the controller?

---

**Question 3**

When or why do you have to use `App::uses()` in a controller or model? I don't understand the point when the models will load anyway if you use the normal methods like `loadModel()`, `hasOne`, `hasMany`, `belongsTo`, etc.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should be simple to understand. If you are using a controller and you need to load another model, you can call:

```
$this->loadModel('SomeModel');
```

Then you can make calls to the model like you normally would:

```
$this->SomeModel->read(null, '1');
```

`App::uses` is for lazy loading of classes. So you can still load a model using uses:

```
App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');
```

But then you will need to call it differently:

```
$MyModel = new MyModel();
$MyModel->read(null, '1');
```

or

```
MyModel::read(null, '1');
```

It just depends on where and how you want to use it.

Comment: I was trying to load a Model from a Behavior, both inside the same Plugin. In this case, You must use: `App::uses('MyModelName', 'MyPluginName.Model');` in the Behavior and `App::uses('MyPluginNameAppModel', 'MyPluginName.Model');` in the called MyModelName file.

Comment: What about using `public $uses = array('Model1', 'Model2');` in the controller?  I would like to know if `$uses` is preferred over `$this->loadModel()`.

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way is

```
$this->load('MyModel');
```

However, you can also use

```
public $uses = array('DefaultModel', 'MyModel');
.
.
$this->MyModel->field(...);
```

Cake supports both and you are free to use anyone you like.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1

As per your structure there is an association between Customer and Country model i think so we don't need to load model.
We can create virtual association for each id such as,

```
 'CountryOrigin' => array(
  'className' => 'Country',
  'foreignKey' => 'country_origin_id',
  'dependent' => true,
  'conditions' => '',
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => '',
  'limit' => '',
  'offset' => '',
  'exclusive' => '',
  'finderQuery' => '',
  'counterQuery' => ''
)


'CountryResidence' => array(
  'className' => 'Country',
  'foreignKey' => 'country_residence_id',
  'dependent' => true,
  'conditions' => '',
  'fields' => '',
  'order' => '',
  'limit' => '',
  'offset' => '',
  'exclusive' => '',
  'finderQuery' => '',
  'counterQuery' => ''
)
```

By doing this we can create  an association between models so we don't want to  load model explicitly

Loading model is good when we don't have an association for that we can use as,

Syntax for load Model is
For single model load

```
$this->loadModel('Country');
```

This will be more useful if we want to load model for particular action or condition

If we wan to use throughout the controller we can use $uses variable
For multiple model load.

```
public $uses = array('Country','OtherModel');
```

we can access model like,

```
$this->Country->find('count');
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way, which is also "more" future proof is the following

```
 $Coordinates = ClassRegistry::init('Coordinates');
 $b = $Coordinates->find('all'....);
```