# CakePHP 2.0 : Accessing unassociated models from a model or its controller?

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Suppose I have **Model1** and it is not associated to **Model2** by hasOne or any other relation. How can I access info from Model2?

I tried the following way:

### Model/Model1.php

```
class Model1 extends AppModel{

public function getInfo(){

  App::uses('Model2','Model');

  $mod2_info=$this->Model2->find('all');
  return $mod2_info;

 }
}//end of class
```

### Controllers/Model1sController.php

```
class Model1sController extends AppController{

public function index(){

 set('info', $this->Model1->find('all'));

 }
}//end of class
```

### View/Model1/index.ctp

```
   <?php var_dump($info);   ?>
```

**Browser Output:**

Fatal error:Call to a member function find() on a non-object in Model/Model1.php

Answer (score 1):

Well there is [the `bindModel` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly), which allows you to create ad-hoc associations.

Of course, using `bindModel` there still have to be valid foreign keys in the model's database table. Alternatively you could use [`loadModel`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel) in *Model1sController*:

`$this->loadModel('Model2');`

The find method of *Model2* then becomes available. `loadModel` is strictly a controller method though, so you can't use it in a model and probably isn't what you're looking for.

Lastly, inside *Model1* you could get a *Model2* instance and use its find method by doing the following:

```
$Model2 = ClassRegistry::init('Model2');
$Model2->find('all');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to handle this, you can use the `$uses` array if every method in your Controller needs to use the model. Use this when a controller necessarily depends on these models.

In this example the ProductionController uses these three Models in all it's methods, so they're incuded in `$uses` as a necessary part of the controller.

```
 var $uses = array('DailyProdn', 'ProdnMode', 'Prod');
```

Note this adds some overhead, so only use `$uses` if this Model is a * necessary part of the controller*. Otherwise, load the Model ad hoc. You can use `$this->loadModel()` to load in a Model inside a method in an ad hoc style.

Here the ProductionController is loading the Plant model. Put this inside a Method before you try to access the Plant Model for `find()` ect. This is great when you need to ad hoc use a Model in just a few Methods.

```
 $this->loadModel('Plant');
```

Answer (score 0):

on top of your first model write this:

```
App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');
```

But then you will need to call it differently:

```
$my_model = new MyModel();
$my_model->anyOtherMethod();
$my_model->read(null, '1');
```

[More info from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584152/best-way-to-load-models-in-cakephp-2-0)