# Cakephp 2.9 alternative for cakephp 3.0 TableRegistry

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

In Cakephp 3.x I can use:

`$myvar = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('tablename')`

To populate `$myvar` with  information.

But what is the equivalent for the code above in CakePhp 2.9?
And which class do I have to add?
In CakePhp 3.x it seems to be `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;`

Comment: Cake 2 and 3 have their own maintenance line and are not compatible that much. In fact, the ORM API has changed a lot. I think the answer to your question depends on what you want to do with that `Cake\ORM\Table`. "To populate $myvar with information." seems a little ambiguous to me; To perform table-level operations or raw queries, just reading some schema or w.e.

Please clear out what your purpose exactly is, so people can exactly tell you the equivalent in cakephp-2.9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get your table in a controller.

In that case, you can load a model like this:

```
$this->loadModel('YourModel');
```

In your controller

```
$this->YourModel
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584152/best-way-to-load-models-in-cakephp-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassRegistry::init('YourModel')->find('first');
```